# Efficient method to retrieve every x-th element from mongodb cursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with about 5 million documents which is still growing. All these documents have a location field. There is an index on the location field aswell. These documents get shown on a map. When I'm zoomed in I only retrieve the points within the bounds of the viewing area with a limit. When zoomed out I want to show x points but not all in one area( x being a lot smaller than the total collection ). I want to implement something like return every 20th element from db, so I get points in every area which should be a good overview at high zoom levels. I've got something like this now and it works, but it's not very fast as I am iterating every item there is.

```
 let itemCount = 0;
 let someItems = [];
 cursor.forEach((item) => {
   if (!(++itemCount % 20)) someItems.push(item);
 }, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   res.json(someItems);
 });
```

The current implementation takes like 5 seconds which is too long for the user to wait in my opinion. Is there like a function to skip cursor items? I've read about the batches which the cursor uses. If the batchSize would be 20 I could just take the first item every batch. I haven't seen a way to retrieve the next batch manually though. What would be a good way to improve the speed of this operation?

PS. I'm using the Node.js MongoDB native driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something akin to a randomised skip list. Basically each time you insert such an item, randomly assign it a "visibility", such that the higher the visibility, the less items have that visibility.

For example, you could use `visibility = floor(log2(random(2^10)))`

Say then you ended up with a series of documents like so:

```
{
  "name": "apple",
  "visibility": 0,
},
{
  "name": "orange",
  "visibility": 0,
},
{
  "name": "banana",
  "visibility": 1,
},
{
  "name": "mango",
  "visibility": 2,
},
```

You can then design your indexes and do your query based on both location and visibility. Increase the minimum visibility in the query to make the items returned more sparse.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. So basically you query based on visibility the further the zoom the higher the visibility and when you zoom in you go for a lower visiblity until you reach the lowest zoom where you show everything?

Comment: yep, that's the idea